# Azure rogue resource eating all my subscription allowance

Tags: azure

I have a student sponsored subscription which gives me $100 allowance.
I created what I thought was a low tier Ubuntu VM.
After 2 days it had used $88 dollars.
There was a table showing the vast majority of the allowance was used by an S70 disk.
I deleted all the resources I could find and created a fresh VM paying close attention not to choose expensive disks.
A day later the remainder of my allowance was used up. And it looked like it was by the same thing.

Anyone got any pointers? I'd like to find the resource listed in my subscription (portal.azure.com) so I can control it (delete it). Or understand how I was able to create a resource that was so expensive.

As it's a student I now have $0, so another question is who can I raise a white flag to to beg for some of the accidentally used allowance back?

According to "https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/free/free-account-students-faq/" I should be able to create a completely free linux VM, but only if I have more than $0 left. :(

Thanks

David

Comment: Don't use premium disks :). Go with standard HDD for your VM.

Comment: I'm certain I went for standard HDD. I remember thinking about the choice. The most likely answer is I made a mistake, but I can't think how!

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. You used a `S70` disk which is a `managed disk`. Based on the pricing page (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/pricing/details/managed-disks/), the cost of a managed disk is about $30 / day. Instead of a managed disk, please use a standard unmanaged HDD.